# Jquery AJAX with ASP.NET WebMethod Returning Entire Page

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I'm doing some simple tests (in preparation for a larger project) to call an ASP.NET WebMethod using JQuery AJAX. In my example, my WebMethod returns a simple string. However, when I attempt to call it using JQuery, I get the entire HTML page content returned instead of just my string. What am I missing?

Client Side :

```
$(document).ready(function ready() {
        $("#MyButton").click(function clicked(e) {
            $.post("Default.aspx/TestMethod",
                {name:"Bob"},
                function(msg) {
                    alert("Data Recieved: " + msg);
                },
                "html"
            );
        });
    });
```

Server Side:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace JqueryAjaxText
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static string TestMethod(string name)
        {
            return "The value submitted was " + name;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion to anyone having these types of problems: please double check the routing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out this link. I used some of his other posts to calll WCF service with success. Be sure to check out the related articles:

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Read through the article but its essentially:

```
  $("#Result").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetDate",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#Result").text(msg.d);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure your web.config contains something equivalent to this, depending on your version: `<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
   </httpModules>
  </system.web>
 </configuration>`

Comment: The key part of this is the line contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" without that line it will return HTML.

Comment: @Nathan I stock in the same problem as the OP about a week, and your answer really help me a lot. Finally I can move on my project. I am really appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

I think I was getting confused with the "type" parameter in JQuery's $.post command. After talking to some folks, it seems that the return type for calling a WebMethod MUST be "json". I was trying to use "html". Once I changed it to "json" and then everything worked like normal. So apparently, a method decorated with [WebMethod] returns JSON only, and that's where my hangup was.

Thanks for your replies guys.

Comment: Yeah, this was getting me as well. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the last parameter "html" to "text".  This parameter specifies the type of data to be returned.

Comment: The problem is, the method is never called. the AJAX call is simply receiving the entire page, rendered just as the browser would see it.

Comment: can you try changing the "html" to "text".?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same problem: WebMethod returned the entire HTML page instead the intended data. For me, the solution came from changing inside **~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs**  the following line:

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

to

```
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;
```