# Jquery , Ajax and ASP.NET webmethods

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

Using query ajax to call a webmethod in an ASP.NET page works well if the HTTP request is a POST. If a HTTP GET request is used the Page_Load event runs instead of the webmethod.
Any ideas?

Here is the Ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://local.proleaguesports.pagefad.com/AjaxTesting.aspx/receivermethod",
        data: "{'test':'MyName'}",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: mycallback,
        error: handler
    });
```

AND here is the code behind in C#

```
public partial class AjaxTesting : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Page_Load runs instead of the receivermethod below");
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true)]
    public static string receivermethod()
    {

        return "test received";

    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Get?  If you do some reading on the internet, you'll find that it opens up some significant security vulnerabilities.  Won't "Post" work?

Comment: John, could you recommend a good Security and HTTPGET article?
I think I will use POST. but, now Im curious :)

Comment: your ajax call is passing back data, but your WebMethod has no parameters

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/752815/626533

Answer (score 0):

You might consider moving your webmethods into a separate web service/asmx. I heard somewhere that calling a webmethod in an aspx causes the entire page to be reloaded, though I can't find a confirming reference for that at the moment.

Comment: No it doesn't. I have a few web methods that work just fine and don't reload the page.

Comment: I've just set a breakpoint in the page_load method of a page that has several webmethods. Calling the webmethod does, indeed, trigger Page_Load(), and I assume everything else that implies.