# jQuery session in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, jquery

I write a countdown timer in jQuery and i need to keep some datas in a session when countdown ends. Datas have to be sent to server to update. How can i handle this situation. I am new in jQuery and asp.net so could you explain this briefly

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supose you have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
```

And an action method like this:

```
public JsonResult Test(string data)
    {
        // do something with data
        var obj = new MyClass {FirstName = "Thiago", LastName = "Temple"};
        return Json(obj);
    }
```

Then you can write a js function using jquery like this:

```
$.get('<%= Html.Action("Test", "MyController")', {data: "some value"}, function(result){
      alert(result.FirstName + " " + result.LastName);
```

});

I hope this example is useful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a one-way communication probably the quickest way is to call an aspx page using the $.get method:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

something like this:

```
$.get('mypage.aspx', myData , function(result) {
   alert('Ok');
});
```

where myData is a JSON object.

for more specific needs you can use the $.ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a PageMethod. You can create it in your codebehind and call it with jQuery.
It's really fast & and great for countdown timers.

Make sure you enable PageMethods in your scriptmanager.

[Call ASP.NET PageMethod/WebMethod with jQuery - returns whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583116/call-asp-net-pagemethod-webmethod-with-jquery-returns-whole-page)

Answer (score 0):

It will be two-way communication both client and server have to communicate each other.