# Page method not called

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, jquery

I set up a page method and am trying to call it through jQuery. Sometimes I get to the success function and sometimes to the error function, seems random to me. In any case, the response contains the entire page mark-up.

I tried using both `$.ajax` and `ScriptManager` with same results.
I also tried the idea here: [Call ASP.NET PageMethod/WebMethod with jQuery - returns whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583116/call-asp-net-pagemethod-webmethod-with-jquery-returns-whole-page) and nothing.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tree").dynatree({
        onActivate: function(node) {
            $('#title').val(node.data.title);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: window.location.href + "/GetData",
                data: "{'ID':22}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response) { alert(response); },
                error: function() { alert('Error!'); }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the c# code:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetData(string ID)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ID))
        throw new Exception("No ID passed!");
    return "Test";
}
```

**Edit:** Well I got it working. I changed the parameter type from int to string and now the method is called. I can just do int.Parse later, but why does this even happen?

Comment: When you use the generated client proxy does it work (i.e. PageMethods.GetData(...)?)

Comment: @dfowler - Nope. Same result.

Comment: Do you routes or anything that might mess with the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is that setting data to `{}` in the jQuery call is the JSON equivalent of setting it to `NULL`. In that case, there is no webmethod that accepts null and the call fails.

Comment: Sorry. I updated the post with the correct version (with the parameter)

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction. Before I had: data: "{'ID':'22'}", so asp.net was looking for a method with parameter type string. Once I removed the ' - everything started working. Thank you!

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something very similar in my current app and the only difference I can see is that i have the following extra option in my ajax call :

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"); }
```

Hope that helps...