# Control Does not go to web method called using JQuery in .net.1.1

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using .net 1.1 and am trying to call a server side method using Jquery when clicking the browser close button.

```
<body  onbeforeunload="javascript:return test()" >
  TESTING  
</body>

function test()
{    
   debugger;   
   $.ajax({    
     type: "GET",    
     url: "HiddenPage.aspx/GetServerTime",   
     data: "{}",    
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",    
     dataType: "json",    
     success: function(msg) 
     {        
       alert(msg.d);     
     },    
     error: function(msg) 
     {       
       alert("Error! Try again...");     
     }          
     return false;          
   })
```

In code behind:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static DateTime GetServerTime()
{
     return DateTime.Now;
}

}
```

The problem is that the control doesnt go to the webmethod.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type to POST.

Comment: Make sure that you are using ScriptManager.

Comment: I am not using ScriptManager,I am using .net1.1

Answer (score -1):

Try to see what the answer is with the program Fiddler.

Comment: i m checking in IE developer tools,msg.d is showing undefined,msg.statusText is ok

Comment: What does the html response give?

Comment: It is returning the whole page back,but control doesnt go to C# method

Comment: Then it probably is on the server side, check this out if it could help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583116/call-asp-net-pagemethod-webmethod-with-jquery-returns-whole-page