# Pass parameter values from JQuery to VB.Net Function

Tags: vb.net, jquery

I have here a vb.net function which accepts 2 parameters and the values that will be passed here will be coming from my jquery code. Is it possible to pass the values from jquery to vb.net? I've already read some solutions but they point out that the vb.net method should be a webmethod. In my case, the vb function is not a web method so that strikes that out. Below are some snippets of my code. Hope you could help me on this.

**JQuery code**

```
$('#TextBox_PRVNo').keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        //basically, pass values from textbox 1 and textbox 2 to VoucherNotClaimed() method
    }
});
```

**VB.Net code**

```
    Private Function VoucherNotClaimed(ByVal strVoucherType, ByVal strPRVNo) As Boolean
        ' TODO: Search in database
        Return True
    End Function
```

Comment: Why can't you use a web method (I think *page method* is the correct term)? It's the "right way" to do this.

Comment: Because it is not a web service but a web application. I believe that using the web method attribute is for web services only.

Comment: You can use web methods for regular asp.net / vb.net web applications, it is not strictly for web services.  So the answer to your question is you cannot call server side code from jquery like that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a web service to decorate your methods with the `WebMethod` attribute. If you do it on a regular page, you create a so-called **page method**. In a nutshell:

1. Create a **public static** method in your page, decorated with the `WebMethod` attribute:

   ```
   <WebMethod()> _
   Public Shared Function VoucherNotClaimed(ByVal strVoucherType, ByVal strPRVNo) As Boolean
       ' TODO: Search in database
       Return True
   End Function
   ```
2. Add a ScriptManager to your ASPX page and [set its `EnablePageMethods` property to `True`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.enablepagemethods.aspx). Also, make sure [your web.config is set up properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/583116/87698).
3. Call your method with JavaScript:

   ```
   var claimed = PageMethods.VoucherNotClaimed(voucherType, prvNo);
   ```

You can find a more detailed explanation in the following MSDN article:

- [Exposing Web Services to Client Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398998.aspx) (Section *Calling Static Methods in an ASP.NET Web Page*)

---

Note that this is the *classic* way to do it. With JQuery, it is also possible to call the page method *without* a ScriptManager; a quick Google search for `page method jquery` yields a huge amount of blog entries going into every possible detail.

Comment: I'll try this one. How about if I want to trigger an event in my textbox (for example)?

Comment: @Musikero31: That sounds like a good subject for another SO question.