# asp.net Polling from database with ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, database, polling

I have looked at all the other questions regarding this and I cant seem to find an answer that fits to my problem.

I have a database filled with measurements and respective datetime for the measurement. I currently use ajax in a asp.net web application to get data from my database(sql server) and make a chart out of that data. The problem is that I have to reload the page in order to see new values that entered the database, meaning that only database values that were present when the page loaded is visible on the web application. I want to poll for new database values every second or so but I cant figure out how to do it in this case.

UPDATED NOW: I have tried to use $.Ajax without any success. I am now trying to return a array 'y' (y values) from a web method and get this from ajax call. See updated code. The problem still lies withing the $.Ajax method in .aspx.

LAST UPDATE: I figured it out after following Josh Mein's step. I had to read documentation and so forth but I learned a lot. If anyone ever encounter a similar problem I will put a comparison below:

.aspx(before):

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jQuery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    setInterval(FillGraph, 1000);
function FillGraph() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/getArray",
        data: '{ }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: OnError
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
    //Fill the graph here i guess(?)
    //I tried alert(response.d) and it didnt return anything.
    }
</script>
```

.aspx (After):

```
function makeChart() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/TestDouble",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(msg.d).length; i++) {
                    yVals[i] = msg.d[i];
                }
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/TestDate",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(msg.d).length; i++) {
                    xVals[i] = msg.d[i];
                }
            }
        });

        var trace1 = {
            x: xVals,
            y: yVals,
            fill: 'tozeroy',
            type: 'scatter'
        };
        var data = [trace1];

        Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
    }
```

aspx.cs (Before):

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static double[] getArray()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = HIDDEN; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("HIDDEN", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }


        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] y = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][0]);
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
        }
        return y;
    }
}
```

aspx.cx (After):

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string[] TestDate()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = WeatherSystem; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("HIDDEN", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
        string[] xArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            xArray[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        }
        return xArray;
    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static double[] TestDouble()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source =localhost\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = HIDDEN; Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("HIDDEN", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
        double[] yArray = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
        //string[] xArray = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //xArray[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            yArray[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][0]);
        }
        return yArray;
    }
```

TestDouble() returns an array of double values. TestDate() returns respective DateTimes to those double values (measurements). GetChart() executes 2 ajax calls, one for Date values and one for Double values. The chart is then filled with these values.

Comment: There are plenty of examples of ajax on SO that should get you headed in the right direction. Just make a WebMethod in your code behind and call it it via `$.ajax`, `$.get`, or `$.post`. When the call returns, use the data to recreate your graph. As it stands right now, your code doesnt even show an attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET jQuery Ajax Calling Code-Behind Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236634/asp-net-jquery-ajax-calling-code-behind-method)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Believe me I have tried $.ajax methods and $.get and so forth. The problem is the content inside those methods, like url, datatype(json?) and so on..

Comment: Have you looked up the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for `$.ajax`? jQuerys documentation is really good.

Comment: If you have tried to use it, update your question with some code showing your attempt. You may be making a simple mistake.

Comment: Hey Josh I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting an error in the console of the browsers developer tools? When you review the network tab in the developer tools, what is the returned response from the ajax call? If you go into debug mode, do you even get to your web method and does it give you the results you expect?

Comment: Just a note, if you arent passing anything in data, there is no point in including the parameter at all.

Comment: Also why are you loading two different versions of jQuery?

Comment: I removed the one now. I get nothing, nothing happens. My question still remains to you guys who know this stuff: How can ajax in this instance fetch the array that i receive from my database in the webmethod?

Comment: There has to be something: an error, the request visible in the network tab, etc. Have you tried step into the method in debug mode?

Comment: Create an onError method and add an `alert` or `console.log`  so you can see if it is failing. These are basic debugging techniques that you need to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, see last update on post for info.