# how to call a a C# server side method from ajax passing parametres to the function with CommandArgument?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a c# method which stores data to sql server. This function is called from an Onlick and i pass the parametres using CommandArgument. Like this.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" onClick="save" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("post_id").ToString() + "," + Eval("user_id").ToString()%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

This is the c# method

```
    protected void vote(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
    string arguments = lb.CommandArgument;
    string[] args = arguments.Split(',');

    string post = args[0];
    string user = args[1];
    .............
  }
```

All i want to do is to call the c# method using ajax because i dont want the page to be refreshed, but i cant call that function passing CommandArgument. I want to use CommandArgument because i dont want the c# method to have other parametres than object sender and EventArgs e

Comment: use webmethod..or use ajax call..or since you tagged asp.net assuming its web form..use updatepanel

Comment: refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27917333/5002329)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET jQuery Ajax Calling Code-Behind Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236634/asp-net-jquery-ajax-calling-code-behind-method)

Comment: J Sushil, thanks for your anwser. I think my problem is different because i want to use CommandArgument which means that i dont want the c# method to have other parametres than object sender and EventArgs e, only to access the parametres using the CommandArgument

Comment: I alse tried script manager and updatepanel with content template but doesnt work. It is still refreshing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" onClick="save" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("post_id").ToString() + "," + Eval("user_id").ToString()%>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

In `script` tag:

```
$("#<%= myVote.ClientID %>").click();
```

Attempt 2:
In `script` tag:

```
var func = $("#<%= myVote.ClientID %>").attr('OnClick');

eval(func);
```

The idea is that Asp.Net WebForms uses JS to do postback to backend, a function generated called `__doPostBack`, the idea is to use the same function and call it, or just inspect the generated HTML of the page and get the value of ,as I remember, `OnClick` attribute of the button, and use it.

This may help also:
[How to use __doPostBack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591634/how-to-use-dopostback)