# jQuery PageMethods 401 Authentication failed with FriendlyUrls

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, webforms

I have FriendlyUrls nuget package added to WebForm application.

In RegisterRoutes I have:

```
var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; 
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

I created 2 pages WebForm1.aspx and WebForm2.aspx

On WebForm1.aspx I referenced jQuery v1.9.1 in the head simply added the following inside the default div tag in the body:

```
<div id="dvResult"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $.fpm("GetCategories", '', function (res) {
                $("div#dvResult").html(res.d);
            }, function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $("div#dvResult").html("<b>" + thrownError + "</b><br/>Status: " + xhr.status + "<br/>" + xhr.responseText);
            });
        });


        $.fpm = function fpm(methodName, arguments, onSuccess, onError) {
            var proto = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
            var hostname = window.location.hostname;
            if (window.location.port != 80)
                hostname = window.location.hostname + ":" + window.location.port;
            var loc = proto + "" + hostname + "/WebForm2.aspx";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: loc + "/" + methodName,
                data: "{" + arguments + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onError
            });
        };

    </script>
```

WebForm2.aspx is kept stock standard after adding the file to the project, except for 1 method added to the code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = false)]
        public static string GetCategories()
        {
            return "hi";
        }
```

When I run the page WebForm1.aspx I get the following result:

```
{"Message":"Authentication failed.","StackTrace":null,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

When view the request in fiddler I can see the friendly url did not strip the .aspx extension (which is a good thing):

```
http://localhost:14918/WebForm2.aspx/GetCategories
```

However as shown above, the FriendlyUrlSettings has the AutoRedirectMode set to RedirectMode.Permanent and when you uncomment the line for RedirectMode.Off and comment the Permanent out, then you actually get the result "Hi" printed on the screen.

Anyone has any ideas what the cause could be or how to add an exclusion to the routes?

I have tried to following but it does not seem to affect in any way the 401 result I keep getting:

```
//routes.Add(new Route("*Remote.aspx*", new StopRoutingHandler()));
 //routes.Ignore("{remote}", new { remote = @".*\Remote.aspx(/.)?" });
```

Answer (score 3):

You just saved my day.Below is the c# version of the code.In case of the master pages just paste  PageMethods.set_path("default.aspx") before closing Content tag

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings,  new CustomFriendlyUrlResolver());
    }

    public class CustomFriendlyUrlResolver : WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver
    {
        public override string ConvertToFriendlyUrl(string path)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo != "")
            {
                return path;
            }
            else
            {
                return base.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is late but in case someone has same issue. Simple fix, set **RedirectMode.Off** instead of **RedirectMode.Permanent**. For the Ajax part do the following for the url key:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url:'<%=ResolveUrl("sample.aspx/methodname")%>'
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function (msg) {
              alert("Worked");
           },
       failure: function (msg) {
              alert("Failed");
           }
});
```

I had similar issue, the above solution worked for me. This is a quick fix but I wouldn't recommend it for production. This error occurs partly because of the FriendlyUrl vs non FriendlyUrl redirect method settings hence the server is receiving requests from an unauthenticated user. For production, make sure to put in place necessary security details and accept request from authenticated users otherwise the exposed methods from code behind can cause a huge security risk.

Answer (score 1):

Faced with stripping vast amounts of PageMethods from a large established application, I found the following alternative solution to switching over to WebApi (turning AutoRedirectMode off still allows my file extensions to be displayed when requested directly and I really don't want that).

Instead use a custom FriendlyUrls.Resolver in your App_Start/RouteConfig file. The only change to existing pages was to add the following markup to each page using PageMethods:

```
<script>PageMethods.set_path("/Pages/Subjects.aspx")</script>
```

Here is the sample code in VB:

```
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers

Public Module RouteConfig
    Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(New FriendlyUrlSettings() With {.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent}, New IFriendlyUrlResolver() {New CustomFriendlyUrlResolver()})
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class CustomFriendlyUrlResolver
    Inherits WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver

    Public Overrides Function ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path As String) As String
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo <> "" Then Return path Else Return MyBase.ConvertToFriendlyUrl(path)
    End Function
End Class
```

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up creating WebApi project and after a few new problems arriving (CORS related), got it working and actually feel that it's probably a better solution than pagemethods.