# Webmethod error with Jquery Ajax post function

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

In an asp.net 3.5 website, I have a jquery located in an ASPX page that should execute a function in code-behind. I have used a webmethod approach.

**Here is the error:**
System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method CloneItem.
Parameter name: methodName

**Here is the relevant code:**

ASPX page with relevant part of Jquery:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/MasterPage.master" Title="Planning" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="PWC" Namespace="PWC" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<PWC:Planning runat="server" SkinFileName="Core/Planning.ascx" ID="Planning" Secured="true"/>

     $("#dialog-form").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         height: 300,
         width: 350,
         modal: true,
         buttons: {
             "Create clone": function () {

                 var cloneItem = $('input[name=item]').is(":checked");                
                 var intID = $(this).data('intID');

                 var bValid = true;
                 bValid = bValid && checkSelections();

                 if (bValid) {

$.ajax(
       {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Planning.aspx/CloneItem',                                  
        data: "{'(intID': '" + $(this).data('intID') + "', 'item': '" + cloneItem + "'}" ,          
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
         // success: cloneOnSuccess,
        // error: cloneOnError
          });

      $(this).dialog("close");
```

Function in Planning.aspx vb code-behind:

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.Services
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _ 
Public Shared Function CloneItem(intID As String, item As Boolean) As String

'execute a stored procedure here

Return "success!"
End Function
```

Master page has the following scriptmanager:

```
  <AJAXToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeOut="600" EnablePartialRendering="true"  CombineScripts="false" ScriptMode="Release" EnablePageMethods="true" >
    </AJAXToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that might be the problem. First thing is you need to some code in web.config.

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

See the reference : [Call ASP.NET PageMethod/WebMethod with jQuery - returns whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583116/call-asp-net-pagemethod-webmethod-with-jquery-returns-whole-page)

Another thing is you need to use JSON.stringify in parameter while posting this data.

See the reference - http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/jquery_webforms_retrieve_data_from_pagemethod.ashx

Comment: Thanks for you response Jalpesh. I already have the web.config reference. However with Json.Stringify I get the error:  JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'stringify'. I have the following code in my Master Page:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"> </script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.json-2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: I have resolved the Stringify error but I'm still getting my original error:  System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method CloneItem. Parameter name: methodName  Any other ideas please?

Comment: did you added reference to ajaxtoolkit?

Comment: Thanks Jalpesh. Yes, AjaxToolkit is fine. I have resolved the issue by moving the Webmethod to the ASPX page itself. The jquery dialog remains in the ASCX page. I'm still not sure why the Webmethod cannot be placed in the ASCX file though.