# Submit a form using AJAX JQuery and ASP.Net with Master Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, forms

I wrote a search program using lucene.net. The search method returns a string containing an html table with the search results. This part works, but I wanted the ability to submit the search without reloading the entire page... So I searched and found that this could be done using AJAX. For whatever reason I cannot get it to work.

I'm not throwing an error. The contents of "Search.aspx" get returned, but it seems like the Submit Method never executes.

Search.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" Runat="Server">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {    

        $(".sBM").click(function () {

            dataString = "valve"

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Search.aspx/Submit",
                //data: dataString,
                data: dataString,
                contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#searchResults").text(msg);
                   alert(msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ErrorText, thrownError) {
                    $("#searchResults").text("Error" + xhr.status);
                }

            });
            return false;
        });

    }); 

</script>

</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">

 <div class="sHead"> 

    <div id="search_form" class="sSBM">
    <form name="search" action=""> 
        <fieldset>  
            <label for="name" id="rpe_label">RPE Search</label>  
            <input type="text" name="query" value="" class="sTM" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="sBM" id="submit_btn" value="" />               
      </fieldset>  
    </form>  
    </div>  

 </div>   

   <div id="searchResults" ></div>     
</asp:Content>
```

CodeFile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [WebMethod]

    public static string Submit(string query) 
    {
        SearchDoc seek = new SearchDoc();
        return seek.Search("valve");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have the `ScriptModule` configured in your web.config to call static page methods like that. If you are running an ASP.NET 3.5 project in Visual Studio using the built-in development web server, make sure this is in your web.config, inside **system.web/httpModules**:

```
<add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

If you are using IIS then make sure this is in your web.config, inside **system.webServer/httpModules**:

```
<remove name="ScriptModule"/>
<add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

If you don't have the right configuration, it is common that a post to Search.aspx/Submit will just return the full page and your web method will not even be called in that case. The role of the `ScriptModule` is to map this request to the web method and return its return value as the response.

---

If that does't work (you already have the right configuration), then try to set your request contentType to `application/json` and perhaps also change the way you pass the query parameter to your web method (also in JSON format):

```
data: { "query": dataString }, 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

See also these similar questions:

- [Call ASP.NET PageMethod/WebMethod with jQuery - returns whole page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/583116/4830)
- [Jquery AJAX with ASP.NET WebMethod Returning Entire Page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/348689/4830)

Answer (score 0):

Well I recent work with a site in ASP.NET, I add a Webservice to my ASP.NET project, and use this snippet in jQuery:

```
        var info = {};
        info.Ticket = ticket;
        info.idCategoria = $('#hidCategoria').val();

        var DTO = { 'info': info };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "MyWebService.asmx/MyTargetFunction",
            data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    // My Logic
                }
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert('Error!');
            }
        });
```

My Webservice are a function like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
public ResponseInfo CrearTicket(CreateTicketInfo info) {
    ResponseInfo i = new ResponseInfo();
    _info = info;

    try
    {
        // Logic Here
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        i.ResponseCode = ContactoConstants.GENERICERROR;
        i.Message = e.Message;
    }

    return i;
}
```